# Unable to post request parameters in swift 3?

Tags: ios, json, swift

Here I am using this Json function to get data from api but after `let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in` this line it's moving to last brace and not executing remaining lines in middle and the output will be array with dictionaries can anyone help me how to get the response for this ?

```
func shippingmethodURL(shippingMethodAPI:String) {
        let url = NSURL(string: shippingMethodAPI)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        print(shippingMethodAPI)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let addtoCartVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "checkout") as! CheckoutViewController
        let parameters : [String: Any] = ["address":
            [ "region": "California",
                "region_code": "CA",
                "region_id": "12",
                "country_id": "US",
                "company": "Test",
                "telephone": "9492162752",
                "postcode": "43",
                "city": "Chennai",
                "firstname": "gdfgdgdfg",
                "lastname": "dgdfgdfgg",
                "email": "sfdsfsdf@gmail.com",
                "prefix": "",
                "sameAsBilling": 1,
                "street": ["Dsfdsfsd dfdsfdsf dsfsfdsfsf sdfsfdsfsdfC"]]]
        print(parameters)
        do {
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)

        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        print(request)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
            }
            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString!)")
            let status = (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode
            self.keyStatusCode = status
            print(status)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you got response from API?

Comment: Do you have anything printed on execution of `dataTask`?

Comment: No I didn't got the response actually the break points didn't enter into the middle lines @SalmanGhumsani

Comment: call `resume()`

Comment: I think you can make it an answer

Comment: previously I used same Json functions to post parameters at that time which now I posted I didn't  use resume() there it is working properly and here it is not working why ? @SalmanGhumsani

Comment: the answer was working thanks @SalmanGhumsani but reason I want for my question which posted above this ?

Comment: @user0246 Could you rephrase, what exactly is the issue?

Comment: previously I used same Json functions to post parameters in different class and there I posted successfully and got response and I didn't use resume() there it is working properly and here it is not working why any reason for this ? @Hexfire

Comment: We don't know how your previous works maybe you don't request with the datatask.

Comment: same function with same parameters to different url and there I used only  two lines extra i.e. `DispatchQueue.main.async`  I used in last @SalmanGhumsani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When you use a dataTask method, you will get back a task object. So You need to call `resume()` on it.**

After you create the task, you must start it by calling its `resume()` method. The task calls methods on the session’s delegate to provide you with the response metadata, response data, and so on.

[Learn about](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1411554-datatask):